# Wait for terminal result before proceeding code

Tags: java, servlets, terminal

I'm posting requests to a Servlet. In that Servlet, I have a code which executes terminal and running some commands there. I want my code to wait the terminal process before it response my requests. How can I manage it?

Below you can see my code:

```
Process send = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"sh", "-c", fileNameShort + ".jar /tmp/"+ fileNameShort +".class; /home/ubuntu/android-x86.rund.sh -cp /tmp/"+ fileNameShort +".jar " + fileNameShort});
```

Comment: You have to get the `OutputStream`, and `ErrorStream` from the Process.  Anything written to the normal STDOUT goes to the OutputStream, anything written to STDERR goes to the ErrorStream.  See the JavaDoc on Process for more info:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Comment: Are you aware that `Process send = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"sh", "-c", fileNameShort + ".jar /tmp/"+ fileNameShort +".class; /home/ubuntu/android-x86.rund.sh -cp /tmp/"+ fileNameShort +".jar " + fileNameShort});` will be executed at server side terminal

Comment: @JqueryLearner yes it is executed in server side terminal. I want my server response to wait that process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Process#waitFor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29):

```
System.out.println("Waiting for process...");
send.waitFor();
```

Comment: when I write send.waitFor(); it shows an error Multiple markers at this line
 - Unhandled exception type InterruptedException
 - Line breakpoint:UploadImage [line: 258] - doPost(HttpServletRequest, 
  HttpServletResponse)

Comment: I expect you to know how to handle it.. Google your *exception* and you'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist");
BufferedReader reader = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader reader = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
System.out.println("Waiting for process completion..");
int exitValue = process.waitFor();
System.out.println("Process is done..");
```

1. Method is `waitFor()` enables you to wait for the process to complete.
2. `ErrorStream` and `InoutStream` enables to get the output & error of the execution respectively
3. `exitValue` indicates manner of completion of the process. exitValue 0 is for normal completion